# ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(LambdaExpression) alternative

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there .NET Framework alternative to `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(LambdaExpression)`?
I need it in some of the projects that cannot reference System.Web.Mvc.

I understand that one of the possibilities is to write my own implementation of `GetExpressionText(LambdaExpression)` method but I don't want to do it. My target is to re-use already existing .NET Framework code.

Comment: What exactly do you need? Could you describe it without referencing that method?

Comment: This method returns name of the property that is specified in lambda expression. If you are familiar with ASP.NET MVC then you should recognize this: `Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID)`. Method `TextBoxFor` is using ExpressionHelper to get the name of the property (i.e., "ID") and generates control with this name. I need the same functionality: from "x => x.SomeProperty" expression I have to get "SomeProperty" as a result

Comment: no alternative i know of. FluentNHibernate for example implemented it's own, too.

Answer (score 9):

Implementing that method yourself is quite easy:

```
string GetPropertyName(LambdaExpression expression)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

If the passed-in lambda is not `MemberExpression`, it will throw an exception (although you might want a more descriptive exception).

If you want to call the method directly like `GetPropertyName(x => x.ID)`, you would need to somehow know what type `x` is. One way is a type parameter:

```
string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

But this would mean you have to specify it explicitly:

```
GetPropertyName<Foo>(f => f.Id)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you read my question carefully? As I wrote "I understand that one of the possibilities is to write my own implementation ... but I don't want to do it". I know how to write such type of methods, in worst case I use Google. Until now @Firo gave the best answer in his comment

Comment: And why don't you want to implement it by yourself? Do you have some reason for that?

Comment: Because I would like to reuse already existing functionality. And, of course, support of this code won't be my problem.

Comment: If he won't do it, I will...upvote for asking the question in the first place, even if he won't use the answer...upvote for the DYI answer.

Comment: @svick your method does not care about complex properties like x=>x.PropertyX.PropertyY, but ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText does!